# What is the actual datastructure used in implementation of collection and their order?

Tags: java, big-o, data-structures

There are different collections are used in Java like hashtable, hashset, vector, treeset, treemap and hashmap. How are they implemented internally? What are the actual datastructure used for these collection? And, What is order?

It would be good if we discuss just a little bit about implementation of collection.

Comment: You can look at the source and find out: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/package-index.html

Comment: Learning the answer to this question could fill an entire semester.

Answer (score 1):

There is this method `Collections.sort()` which internally calls `Arrays.sort()`. This uses the merge sort to sort data which has the order O(nlogn). And one more information is, if the number of elements to be sorted is lesser than 7, it uses the insertion sort.

As with `Vector` and `ArrayList` following are the complexities since it uses a simple array

- get(index) - O(1)
- add(Object) - O(n)
- insertAt(int pos, Object value) - O(n)
- remove(Object) - O(n)

One more thing is that `HashSet` internally uses a `HashMap` only worrying about the keys of a map and the objects being ignored or unused so that there are no two different implementations. And HashMap uses the collision free or the ideal hashing by generating unique hashcodes for every object. So, the order would be ideally 1 for insertion and retrieval of data.

Often in Java Collections, especially in Lists, there is this usual comparison between its two concrete implementations, the `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. The order of the LinkedList are as follows.

- get(index) - O(n)
- add(Object) - O(1) (provided a readymade last pointer is maintained in the linked list)
- insertAt(int pos, Object value) - O(n)
- remove(Object) - O(n)

Answer (score 0):

The collections implementation classes are named exactly after their data structures. So HashSet and HashMap used a hash as the underlying data structure, while TreeSet and TreeMap use a binary tree.

More info is available in the JavaDoc of those classes. For example, for [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) it states:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Answer (score 0):

Related to Order I find something useful:

I found below post very useful in respect to Big O notation:
[Big-O summary for Java Collections Framework implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations)

and in precise below webpage
http://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/

below details about experiment result on each collection
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAlgorithms.fm.html

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [illuminating](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pldi09tutorials/memory-efficient-java-tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add one correction in bragBoy Answer :

The **worst complexity for remove in LinkedList Collections should be O(1)** as its **internally uses the Doubly Linked List Data structure** which makes easy to delete a single specific Object.