# Why would iterating over a List be faster than indexing through it?

Tags: java, list, iterator

Reading the [Java documentation for the ADT List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) it says:

> The List interface provides four methods for positional (indexed) access to list elements. Lists (like Java arrays) are zero based. Note that these operations may execute in time proportional to the index value for some implementations (the LinkedList class, for example). Thus, iterating over the elements in a list is typically preferable to indexing through it if the caller does not know the implementation.

What exactly does this mean? I don't understand the conclusion which is drawn.

Comment: Another example that may help you understand the general case of this is [Joel Spolsky's article "Back to Basics"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) - search for "Shlemiel the painter's algorithm".

Answer (score 210, accepted):

In a linked list, each element has a pointer to the next element:

```
head -> item1 -> item2 -> item3 -> etc.
```

To access `item3`, you can see clearly that you need to walk from the head through every node until you reach item3, since you cannot jump directly.

Thus, if I wanted to print the value of each element, if I write this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

what happens is this:

```
head -> print head
head -> item1 -> print item1
head -> item1 -> item2 -> print item2
head -> item1 -> item2 -> item3 print item3
```

This is **horribly inefficient** because every time you are indexing it restarts from the beginning of the list and goes through every item. This means that your complexity is effectively `O(N^2)` just to traverse the list!

If instead I did this:

```
for(String s: list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

then what happens is this:

```
head -> print head -> item1 -> print item1 -> item2 -> print item2 etc.
```

all in a single traversal, which is `O(N)`.

Now, going to the other implementation of `List` which is `ArrayList`, that one is backed by a simple array. In that case both of the above traversals are equivalent, since an array is contiguous so it allows random jumps to arbitrary positions.

Comment: Minor notice: LinkedList will search from the end of the list if the index is in the later half of the list, but that doesn't really change the fundamental inefficiency. It makes it only slightly less problematic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know if this is the same for C# (or other similar languages)?

Comment: *This is horribly inefficient*. For larger LinkedList -yes, for smaller it can work faster  `REVERSE_THRESHOLD` is set 18 in `java.util.Collections`, it's weird to see so upvoted answer without the remark.

Comment: @DanDiplo, if the structure is Linked, yes it holds true. Using LinkedS structures, however, is a small mystery. They almost always perform far worse than array backed ones (extra memory footprint, gc-unfriendly and terrible locality). Standard list in C# is array backed.

Comment: @bestsss: When I said "horribly inefficient" I was making a comment about asymptotic performance, hence my O(N^2) vs O(N) analysis. Of course, for small data sets many such reasonings do not apply, since also for N < 8 insertion sort is faster than mergesort or quicksort.

Comment: sure, about n^2, no doubt (even though LinkedList is doubly-linked, it's still n^2). However, for a LinkedList it might prove useful to keep the last 1-3 indexes cached. Then a full loop via get(prev+1)/get(prev-1) would yeild O(n) [wow!]. Sure the cache is to be invalidated on each modification but it's already taken care via `modCount`. The change is trivial and it can help poorly written code w/ very minor performance degrade of get(index) which perform poorly to boot.

Comment: Minor notice: If you want to check which iteration type should be used (indexed vs Iterator/foreach), you can always test if a List implements [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) (a marker interface): `List l = unknownList();
if (l instanceof RandomAccess)
  /* do indexed loop */
else
  /* use iterator/foreach */`

Comment: @Tudor **+1** for nice explanation I have one question .. Is  <pre><code>for(String s: list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}</code></pre>  and    <pre><code>List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
     {
  String string = (String) iterator.next();
  }</code></pre>  **are equally efficient ??** if not then which is more **efficient**

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585: Actually the enhanced for loop in your first example is compiled into an iterator like in the second example, so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 35):

The answer is implied here:

> Note that these operations may execute in time proportional to the index value for some implementations (the LinkedList class, for example)

A linked list doesn't have an inherent index; calling `.get(x)` will require the list implementation to find the first entry and call `.next()` x-1 times (for a O(n) or linear time access), where an array-backed list can just index into `backingarray[x]` in O(1) or constant time.

If you look at the [JavaDoc for `LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), you'll see the comment

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

whereas [JavaDoc for `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has the corresponding

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to store the list. (This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except that it is unsynchronized.)
>
> The `size`, `isEmpty`, `get`, `set`, `iterator`, and `listIterator` operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the `LinkedList` implementation.

A [related question titled "Big-O Summary for Java Collections Framework"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations) has an answer pointing to this resource, ["Java Collections JDK6"](http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf) which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 8):

While the accepted answer is most certainly correct, might I point out a minor flaw. Quoting Tudor :

> Now, going to the other implementation of List which is ArrayList,
>   that one is backed by a simple array. **In that case both of the above
>   traversals are equivalent**, since an array is contiguous so it allows
>   random jumps to arbitrary positions.

This is not completely true. The truth is, that

> With an ArrayList, a hand-written counted loop is about 3x faster

[source: Designing for Performance, Google's Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach)

Note that the handwritten loop refers to the indexed iteration. I suspect its because of the iterator which is used with enhanced for loops. It produces a minor performance in penalty in a structure which is backed by a contiguous array. I also suspect this might be true for the Vector class.

My rule is, use the enhanced for loop whenever possible, and if you really care about performance, use indexed iteration only for either ArrayLists or Vectors. In most cases, you can even ignore this- the compiler might be optimizing this in the background.

I merely want to point out that in the context of development in Android, both the traversals of ArrayLists are **not necessarily equivalent**. Just food for thought.

Comment: Your source is Anndroid only. Does this hold for other JVMs as well?

Comment: Not completely sure tbh, but again, using enhanced for loops should be the default in most cases.

Comment: It makes sense to me, getting rid of all the iterator logic when accessing a data structure that uses an array works faster. I don't know if 3x faster, but certainly faster.

Answer (score 8):

Iterating over a list with an offset for the lookup, such as `i`, is analogous to *Shlemiel the painter's algorithm*.

> Shlemiel gets a job as a street painter, painting the dotted lines
>   down the middle of the road. On the first day he takes a can of paint
>   out to the road and finishes 300 yards of the road. "That's pretty
>   good!" says his boss, "you're a fast worker!" and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel only gets 150 yards done. "Well, that's not
>   nearly as good as yesterday, but you're still a fast worker. 150 yards
>   is respectable," and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel paints 30 yards of the road. "Only 30!" shouts
>   his boss. "That's unacceptable! On the first day you did ten times
>   that much work! What's going on?"
>
> "I can't help it," says Shlemiel. "Every day I get farther and farther
>   away from the paint can!"

[Source](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

This little story may make it easier to understand what is going on internally and why it is so inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

To find the i-th element of a `LinkedList` the implementation goes through all elements up to the i-th.

So

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length ; i++ ) {
    Object something = list.get(i); //Slow for LinkedList
}
```