# Android ArrayList iteration

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which stores Area names. I want to check this list to find whether arbitrary people are from different area. If they are from different area, i take a decision. I achieved this with the following code. Note that area_IdList  and area_IdListduplicate are essentially the same ArrayList. Is this code efficient or can anyone suggest more efficient code ? Thanks in Advance.

```
public List<String> area_IdList = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> area_IdListduplicate = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < area_IdList.size(); i++) 
{  
    for (int k = 1; k< area_IdListduplicate.size(); k++)
    {
        String sa= area_IdListduplicate.get(k);
        String sb= area_IdList.get(i);
        if (!sa.equalsIgnoreCase(sb))
        { 
            some decision
        }
    }             
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve? Right now you are taking a decision if they are NOT from the same area!

Comment: for (int k = i+1;......will more efficient

Comment: @carnal i edited my question..sorry for the mistake. i want to find whether they are from different area

Comment: @zetsin: k = i +1 will skip the first index (0) and give him OutOfBoundException when attempting to get the last element if they have the same size

Comment: @Carnal: Note that area_IdList and area_IdListduplicate are essentially the same ArrayList. as his meaning, the first index(0) is not necessary to compare. And if they have the same size, OutOfBoundException will not be happended

Comment: @zetsin: read my comment again.

Comment: @Carnal: As his meaning, the first index(0) is not necessary to be compared. And if they have the same size, it will not step into the second for loop, so OutOfBoundException will not be happended

Comment: @zetsin: you're right mate about the not getting "OutOfBoundException", I thought about list.get(i + 1), misread it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (String area : area_IdList) 
{  
    for (String duplicatedArea : area_IdListduplicate)
    {
        if (!area.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicatedArea))
        { 
            // some decision
        }
    }             
}
```

This  is more efficient, goes faster instead of iterating by indexes.
So this will check step by step each element in `area_IdList` with all elements in `area_idListduplicate` and each time they don't mach, this decision will be made. (If that's what you want achieve)

Comment: `goes faster instead of iterating by indexes`. What do you mean?

Comment: When you iterate by indexes = it starts over from index 0 again.
When you iterate with what I wrote = it goes straight through with out starting over. This is the way it works, nothing you will see in code though.

Comment: @Carnal don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @TJ Thind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486507/why-would-iterating-over-a-list-be-faster-than-indexing-through-it/10486601#10486601

Comment: @Carnal Are you referring to linked list traversal? That wouldn't be an issue here since the collection being used is an ArrayList which is backed by an array.

Comment: @TJ Thind: you're right. I was wrong about it being faster.

Comment: @Your solution isn't necessarily wrong. It might be faster if it were using a different collection or on a device without JIT. A better way would be to reduce the complexity of the algorithm. This can be done without nested loops.

Answer (score 6):

This is a O(2N) solution at some cost of 2N memory instead of N^2 time and N memory cost. Depends on the number of items that you have, but this solution will cost significantly less than the N^2 solutions.

```
  Set<String> list=new Set<String>();
  for (String area : area_IdList) 
  {  
    list.add(area.toLowerCase());
  }

  for (String duplicatedArea : area_IdListduplicate)
  {
    if(list.contains(duplicatedArea.toLowerCase())){
      //Do something
    }
  }
```

As for not using index, see [Use Enhanced For Loop Syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html)

Comment: In terms of algorithm complexity, this is more efficient than the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 for(String areaId : area_IdList){
    if(!area_IdListduplicate.contains(areaId){
    //some decision
    }
    }
```