# Most efficient way to access variables in List<String> in Java

Tags: java

I've got lots of data stored like this

```
["5368","45946","532.3602831594635","8.559239940387481"]
```

That I have to iterate over.

What is the most efficient way to access these variables?

Currently I'm deserializing into a List> however and accessing get(0).get(0) or whatever, but it's slow on big amounts of data.

Comment: Sorting and searching.

Comment: Is it  one-way list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a List in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Just access each value. Currently I'm deserializing into a List<List<String>> however and acessing get(0).get(0) or whatever, but it's slow on big amounts of data.

Comment: What kind of `List`?  If it's a `LinkedList`, then using `.get(n)` is a linear operation, and will be slow for large lists.  You could change the underlying type to an `ArrayList` which is constant time for `.get(n)`, or alternatively use an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be faster using JAVA8 Stream and parallel forEach.

```
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // .....
    list.stream().parallel()
        .forEach(sublist -> sublist.stream().parallel()
             .forEach(element -> /* do something to element */));
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Why would iterating over a List be faster than indexing through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486507/why-would-iterating-over-a-list-be-faster-than-indexing-through-it)
Iterating is quite simple, but what you'll do when iterating is more relevant to speed efficiency.