# How to store strings into hashmap/hashtable?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

My CS fundamental is slipping away....

How do you store a large number of strings into hashmap/hashtable, so that you can have a lookup time of that string of O(1)?...

Isn't there a java library for hashmap/hashtable?...
It seems to store a value to hashmap, you have to store 'key' & 'value'. I assume 'value' is the string I'm trying to store, so what do I have to do sofr the 'key'?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)...

Comment: Whatever you want. What do you want to lookup by? Not a real question.

Comment: Elaborate more plz, How do you want to retrieve the stored strings?

Comment: Oh, yes I think I was looking for HashSet. Thank you Oli. I was confused with HashTable/HashMap/HashSet :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has built-in support; please see the [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class.

If you just want values stored, then perhaps a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) would be a better choice for when the key is the value.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm just really confused because I cant remember what I am suppose to do if I'm just trying to list of strings into hashtable/hashmap. Am I suppose to be using method Map.put("Hello","Hello"), to store string "Hello" into hashmap?

Comment: Edited my answer to include HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there a java library for hashmap/hashtable?

Yes there is.  In fact, there are 3 classes in the Java SE library that roughly match your requirements.  (Hint: HashSet, HashMap, Hashtable.)

You can find them easily by searching the Javadocs online.  Start here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html

And if one of those doesn't match your requirements, there are specialist 3rd party libraries ... which you can probably find using Google.

---

If you are going to be successful as a Java programmer, you need to learn some "search fu" so that you can find these classes for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to lookup by key then use HashMap; if you don't and are happy with indexed access then use ArrrayList.

See following for Big-O discussion:

- http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf
- [Big-O summary for Java Collections Framework implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations)