# Time complexity of LinkedList, HashMap, TreeSet?

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity

I am a student of CS, learning about Java Collections.
At my school we have received a chart with with time complexity of different operations on data structures. There are some things in the chart that don't make sense to me.

**Linked List**
It says that time complexity for inserting at the end and finding the number of elements is implementation dependent. Why is that? Why isn't it O(n)?

**HashMap**
For the HashMap it says that tc for finding number of elements or determining whether the hashMap is empty has also tc implementation dependent.

**TreeMap** same goes for the TreeMap. According to the chart, the tc of the operation to determine the number of elements is implementation dependent. Which implementation do they mean?

Comment: You can read [this good article](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashset-vs-treeset-vs-linkedhashset/).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Duzhe diakuju! Thank you!

Comment: @Lrrr LinkedList, HashMap and TreeMap are not interfaces, they implement interfaces List and Map as far as I know

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why this kind of question is downvoted? Ok, I understand, it is not the most complex issue of computer science, but as a beginner it is sometimes difficult to understand the nuances, even after reading the API and searching through other answers. We have all been noobs at some point. What is the problem?

Comment: If you hover over the upvote and downvote buttons, a piece of text appears explaining their purpose. In this case, I would imagine it's "does not show any research effort".

Comment: How am I supposed to show it? Write an essay on what I already know on the subject and create a PowerPoint presentation? Or give a list of links I have visited researching the subject with a shot summary? I am not asking to explain to me what a TreeMap is. But anyway, I am getting used to this on StackOverflow. At least there still good people willing to help out without downvoting you to the point you can't post a question anymore. Anyway, I have a right to ask, people have a right to downvote, that's what it boils down to.

Comment: You say _Why isn't it O(n)?_. Stating why you think it should be `O(n)` would be good enough for me (for that example).

Comment: [HashMap get/put complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity) gives a good explanation wrt HashMaps/Sets, [Big O summary for java collections implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations) also has info on lists and tree maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some implementations of `LinkedList` can keep a count of the number of elements in their list as well as a pointer to the last element for quick tail insertion. This means that they are done O(1) as it is a quick data access.

Similar reasoning can be followed for implementations of `HashMap` and `TreeSet`, if they keep a count of the number of elements with their data structure  then functions such as `isEmpty()` and `size()` can be done O(1) also.