# Removing all of a certain value from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Is their a prebuilt method that works differently than `removeAll` to remove all of a certain value in an array list?

I have a method to delete duplicates in arrayLists that looks like this:

The first 2 for for loops work and set it correctly but I don't know what to do for the second for loop to delete all values of -1 from the ArrayList or is their a better way to do this?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> deleteDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> a) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = (i + 1); j < a.size(); j++) { 
        if (a.get(i) == a.get(j) && i != j) {
          a.set(j, -1); 
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      if (a.get(i) == -1) {
        a.removeAll(int -1);
      }
    }
```

The `removeAll(int -1)` thing at the bottom doesn't compile, I just left it there so you can see what I'm trying to do.

EDIT:

replaced the for loop at the bottom with this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      if (a.get(i) == -1) {
        a.remove(i);
        i--;
      }
    }
```

pretty sure that works.

Comment: Please explain this line `if (a.get(i) == -1)`

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates have you considered using a set/hashset?

Comment: a.remove(i);

Since you are using for loop to check every element one by one there is no need to use removeall, just use a.remove(i);

There is a better way to remove the duplicates by putting them into a set, set cannot contain duplicated value so it removes the duplicate automatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be _very_ careful with `List<Integer>` - there is `remove(int)` which removes the item at a specified index, and `remove(Integer)` which removes the object specified. Due to autoboxing conventions, it can be _very_ easy to call the wrong method, often resulting in a lot of frustrating debugging.

Comment: `removeAll(Collections.singleton(-1))` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A possibly less efficient, but far more readable way of accomplishing this is to use a Set to filter the duplicates:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> deleteDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
   return new ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(a));
}
```

For most cases, like very large Lists, this will be a better option.

Given the option, avoid the need to convert an `ArrayList` all together by declaring your initial `ArrayList<Integer>` as a `Set<Integer>`. If so, this method would be come unnecessary.

Comment: I tried the TreeSet thing and I get the error message: .java:22: error: illegal start of expression
    ArrayList<Integer> b = ArrayList<>(new TreeSet<Integer>(a));
                                     ^
1 error

Comment: I updated the code in the answer to help correct your issue.

Comment: this is declaring a set so I have the line of code:    ArrayList<Integer> b = ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(a)); and then I have a really basic for loop that deletes the duplicates after its sorted but the first line gives me the error message: Generate.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
     ArrayList<Integer> b = ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(a));
                            ^
  symbol:   variable ArrayList
  location: class Generate

Comment: and these: Generate.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
     ArrayList<Integer> b = ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(a));
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable Integer
  location: class Generate
Generate.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
     ArrayList<Integer> b = ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(a));
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class TreeSet
  location: class Generate
3 errors

Comment: you need to have an import statement for both ArrayList and TreeSet, both can be imported with the statement at the top of your class: `import java.util.*;`

Comment: A `LinkedHashSet` would be better, since it will retain the original order of the values. It may even perform better. Since the input is a `List`, order may be important.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the most elegant way would be to use a Set; which takes care of duplicate values automatically.

I would even go one step further: if you have control over the input data ... then do not use an ArrayList at all. It is simply a waste of memory and CPU cycles to first fill a list with values; to then transform it into a Set to eliminate duplicates; to then turn that into a list again. You are constantly creating new objects without the need to.

Instead: use a set right from the beginning. So, if possible change the code that "receives" the input data to directly store within a set.

( side note: the different collection classes like HashSet, ArrayList, ... have different "cost" for different kinds of operations. In that sense you might want to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations) to determine which collection type best fits your needs )