# Best data structure to store 10,000 records in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this in interview. I thought the question was too generic to specify a particular data structure.

However, still if we channelize the question to following criterion what would be the best data structure to use:

1. If insertion speed should be fastest?
2. If search of particular data is to be the fastest?

Comment: Have a look at [big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations). You'll find the answer there.

Comment: Usually they might want you to come up with more questions to clarify their question like - what do you want to use the records for? the dataset rarely changes - mostly reading? the dataset does insert and remove a lot?

Comment: For faster insertions - Linked List, for faster searches - binary search tree, which one is more important ?

Comment: According to [bigocheatsheet.com/] , Hashtable is fastest for Search Insertion Deletion with O(1) .So why not use Hashtable every time to store anything ??

Comment: @user2713255: Because a hash table doesn't guarantee enumeration order, a hash table will require much more space than a list or array, and you can't in general index a hash table by position. A hash table is a good tool, but it's not a Swiss Army knife.

Answer (score 7):

The `HashSet` provides both O(1) insertion and O(1) search, which is hard to top from a theoretical point of view.

In practice, for a size of 10.000 references, a sorted `ArrayList` might still outperform `HashSet`, although insertion is O(n) and search is O(log(n)). Why? Because it stores the data (the references at least) in a contiguous memory range and therefore can take advantage of hardware memory caching.

The issue with big-O notation is that it completely ignores the time required for a single operation. That's fine for asymptotic considerations and very huge data sets, but for a size of 10.000 it might be misleading.

Haven't tried it, though. And I bet your Interviewer hasn't either :).