# If I'm building a linkedhashmap and return a map, would my calling function have a linkedhashmap

Tags: java, polymorphism, linkedhashmap

I have a method where I build a `LinkedHashMap` so I can preserve order. Here is my method:

```
public class MyClass {

    public Map<String,MyObj> buildMap() {
        Map<String,MyObj> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        //perform logic and add objects to myMap
        ...
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

When I'm calling my `buildMap()` function from another class, would I get a map that is in order still? Like:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Map<String, MyObj> returnedMap = myClass.buildMap();
```

would my `returnedMap` still be a `LinkedHashMap`?

Or would I have to change my `buildMap` function to always return a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: You're returning the instance of `myMap`. This does not change until there is something like `myMap = new ...`. So yes, the calling class will get a `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: the reason I'm asking is I would want to keep my buildMap() function generic and I know it is usually recommended to program against the interface (Map) rather than an implementation of that interface (LinkedHashMap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter what type or interface is returned. The object instance type does matter however. If it is a `LinkedHashMap` then it will preserve the implementation, so the order in your case.

> This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally
>   chaotic ordering provided by `HashMap` (and `Hashtable`), without
>   incurring the increased cost associated with `TreeMap`. It can be used
>   to produce a copy of a map that has the same order as the original,
>   regardless of the original map's implementation:
>
> ```java
>  void foo(Map m) {
>      Map copy = new LinkedHashMap(m);
>      ...
>  }
> ```

Comment: so even though my returnedMap is just a generic map, it would still preserve order? If I add and remove elements from the returnedMap after it would still act as a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: if you return `LinkedHashMap` then it will act like `LinkedHashMap` otherwise not.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is correct - it doesn't matter what *return type* you use within your source code in order to express your thinking.

At runtime, the only thing that matters about the nature of an object is  its concrete, specific class.

But the one aspect to consider: if "keeping insertion order" is a **core** element of the API you are providing to the user, you *might* change the signature of your method to:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String,MyObj> buildMap() {
```

to simply make it **clear** to all future users of this method what the method is doing.

You see, LinkedHashMap and HashMap have *slightly* different [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations) characteristics. Depending on your context, it *could* be important for future callers to understand that the method will in fact return this special Map implementation.

But in mos situations, that difference doesn't matter, and then it is "good practice" to return the more abstract interface type instead of the specific implementation class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java) for some further reading why to prefer *interface* types in general.

Comment: It was not me but I argument to coding to interfaces rather than classes.

Comment: Writing code is always about expressing intentions. When the intention is: "here linked hash map" then it might be better to make that explicit.

Comment: The code works exactly as it's written, and user prefer working with interfaces rather than classes implementing those interfaces.

Comment: Why the absolute? I **prefer** understanding the *intention* of the code I am working with. As long as the reasons are valid, it is perfectly fine to *violate* rules at certain points. If programming would only following rules, computers could do it.

Comment: The intention of the code is its specification, that points to interfaces. If you need details about implementation that might be different then you should read javadoc or look at the source code.

Comment: The **best** choice to express design decisions is by using **code**. Telling somebody "read the source / javadoc" means that you *failed* to express something essential within code. Most often that is because Java code isn't expressive enough. But again: in certain situations it can be important that everybody understands "we are using a XYMap" and not use just "any Map" implementation. That is all I am saying. And that is based on my **own** experience. There is no point in you declaring: in 100% of all cases you use the interface. Because I have seen..

Comment: enough situations were deviating from that rule **helped**.