# What is the time complexity of this bit of pseudocode

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

```
for loop {
    initialize new hashmap 
    for loop {
        if (hashmap.containsKey(i)
             map.put(something)
    }
}
```

basically 2 nested for loops with a containsKey function inside it.

im thinking its O(n^2) because of the nested loops but it could also be O(n^3) because of the containsKey function. could someone help me out here?

Comment: `HashMap.containsKey()` is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on which implementation of the map is being used on your code.Suppose, for HashMap implementaion, it is **O(1)**, but for TreeMap implementaion it **O(log(N))**. For details, you can see these:

[Big-O summary for Java Collections Framework implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-

So, if you use HashMap, then time complexity is **O(N^2)**, and if you use TreeMap, it will be **O(N^2)(log(N))** in your case.